# Phonegap workflow

Tags: cordova, workflow

I'm trying to work out the best workflow for building apps with Phonegap.

At the moment, I make a change to my www folder and then run 'phonegap build ios' to then compile the app in Xcode to view on my device. It seems very long winded.

How are you working with Phonegap?

Cheers

Chris

Answer (score 1):

i worked with PhoneGap, although i done my work for Android through eclipse i had to follow the same long winded routine.

PhoneGap has its benefits but regarding the quick testing of items i found it to be easier using a virtual device. I also found another way of testing things quickly by running the app locally in the browser, so when i had all the HTML and javascript functioning i started looking at changing the CSS through deploying to a my device, this made the HTML development pretty quick.

Another possibility is to turn on automatic build for your development, this would mean one less step.

Hope something i said here helps.